# Finding max sum contiguous subarray when atmost k elements can be omitted?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, dynamic-programming

Eg- `n=10`
`arr[]={6,-5,3,-7,6,-1,10,-8,-8, 8}`
`For k=0, best segment is 5-7 with sum=15.
For k=2, best segment is 1-7 with sum=24.
For k=6, best segment is 1-10 with sum=33.`
Given array and k, find sum.

I think, let `dp[i][j]` denote the maximum segment ending at position i with at most j elements dropped. Inductively compute `dp[i][j]`from `dp[i][j-1]`. But how to keep track of elements removed from `dp[i][j-1]` and not to remove them again??? I am confused in dp problems. I want to know dp approach and some other approach if possible?

Comment: Consider computing dp[i][j] from dp[i-1][j] and dp[i-1][j-1] and ignoring dp[i][j-1]

Answer (score 2):

Let `m(i, j)` represent the maximum sum ending at index `i` with exactly `k` omissions. Then

```
m(i, j) = max(
  // Use A[i-1]
  // (same number of omissions: j)
  A[i-1] + max(0, m(i - 1, j)),

  // Omit A[i-1]
  // (reference j-1 since we are
  // adding an omission here)
  m(i - 1, j - 1)
)
```

To get the answer for *at most* `k` omissions, we consider the results for all different exact `k`s. (Note that the space can still be reduced to `O(n)` since only the previous and current rows are needed.)

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, k){
  console.log(`Input: ${ JSON.stringify(A) }\n\n`);

  let m = new Array(A.length + 1);
  
  let result = 0;

  // Initialize Array
  for (let i=0; i<=A.length; i++)
    m[i] = new Array(k + 1).fill(0);

  // Zero omissions (Kadane's algorithm)
  for (let i=1; i<=A.length; i++){
    m[i][0] = A[i-1] + Math.max(0, m[i-1][0]);
    result = Math.max(result, m[i][0]);
  }
  
  for (let i=1; i<=A.length; i++){
    for (let j=1; j<=k; j++){
      m[i][j] = Math.max(
        A[i-1] + Math.max(0, m[i-1][j]),
        m[i-1][j-1]
      );
      
      result = Math.max(result, m[i][j]);
    }
  }
  
  for (let row of m)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    
  return result;
}

let A = [6, -5, 3, -7, 6, -1, 10, -8, -8, 8];
let k = 6;

console.log(f(A, k));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can focus on two cases i.e., **firstly**, a continuous(without deletion) sub-array(non-empty) ending at some index or **secondly**, a sub-array with deletion(s), ending at some index. Then we can choose whether to add the current array element with our previous state result. Looking carefully, all the cases can be handled with these.

The zero-deletion case can be considered as the base case; We can think the overall mathematical relation to be something like   *f(x,k)=max(f(x-1,k) + a[x], f(x-1, k-1))* with some conditions and edge cases, where f(x,k) is the solution up to x-index with at-most k deletions. Also in that regard, f(x,k-1), denotes the solution up-to x-index with at-most k-1 deletions, is not really necessary anymore as we already have the relation of current and previous state. Here is my solution...

```
int maxSumWithKdel(vector<int> a, const int k) {
        int n = a.size();
        vector<vector<int>> dp(n, vector<int> (k + 1));
        int res = a[0];
        // base case ~ zero deletions ~ kadanes
        for(int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            dp[x][0] = max((x == 0 ? 0 : dp[x - 1][0]) + a[x] , a[x]);
            res = max(res, dp[x][0]);
        }
        // at-most k deletions
        for(int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            for(int d = 1; d <= k; d++) {
                if(x != 0) {
                    dp[x][d] = max(dp[x - 1][d - 1], dp[x - 1][d] + a[x]);
                } 
                else {
                    dp[x][d] = a[x];  // edge case handelling
                }
                res = max(res, dp[x][d]);
            }
        }
        return res;
}
```